# When trying to submit the preview for mturk request I receive the following error. Why?

Tags: html, mechanicalturk

I have a categorization request that I am trying to put together on mturk. When I preview the widget I can select a category but receive the following error when I hit submit.

> "There was a problem submitting your results for this HIT.
>
> This HIT is still assigned to you. To try this HIT again, refresh the
>   page. If this problem persists, you can contact the Requester for this
>   HIT by clicking "HIT Details" above and then clicking "Contact This
>   Requester" at the bottom of the pop up.
>
> To return this HIT and continue working on other HITs, click the
>   "Return" button on the top or bottom of the right side of the page."

my code is as follows:

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="workContent">
<h2>${snippet}</h2>

<h2><a href="${web_url}">Full Article</a></h2>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 fields">
<div class="form-group"><!-- Question for the Worker --><label class="group-label">Choose a category (The box will not stay highlighted):</label> <!-- Input from the Worker -->

<div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons" id="CategoryInputs"><label class="btn btn-default"><input id="category1" name="categories" required="" type="radio" value="AnarchistEvent" />Anarchist Event</label> <label class="btn btn-default"> <input id="category2" name="categories" required="" type="radio" value="NonAnarchistEvent" />Non-Anarchist Event</label> <!-- Add more inputs by copy pasting the "label" container and incrementing/changing the "id" attribute on the "input" field to always be unique. Make sure the "value" attribute has the correct value that you want recorded as a response. --></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the actual mturk tooling. Despite throwing these errors in the preview tool, this code works just fine.